# Delphi: Unique variable for each TIdcontext

Tags: delphi, variables, indy10

I am having issue with declaring a unique global variable for each connection of IdTCPServer. What i am trying to do here is.

```
TMyContext = class(TIdServerContext)
  public
    Tag: Integer;
    Queue: TIdThreadSafeList;
    FPacketBuffer: Pointer;
    PacketBufferPtr: Integer;

    constructor Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TThreadList = nil); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

and then accessing the variable using TMyContext(AContext).FPacketBuffer, but i get an access violation error when there is a connection active and a new connection tries to connect. here is what is in my idTcpConnect and idTcpDisconnect

```
procedure TMainFrm.MainSckConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TMyContext(AContext).Queue.Clear;
  TMyContext(AContext).Tag := -1;
  GetMem(TMyContext(AContext).FPacketBuffer,65536);
end;

procedure TMainFrm.MainSckDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
Var Client: TClientInfo;
begin
//If TMyContext(AContext).Queue.Count > 0 Then TMyContext(AContext).Queue.Clear;
TMyContext(AContext).Queue.Clear;
FreeMem(TMyContext(AContext).FPacketBuffer);
If AContext.Data <> nil Then Begin
  Client := Pointer(AContext.Data);
  Clients.Remove(Client);
  Client.Free;
  AContext.Data := nil;
End;
end;
```

The error occures when getmem is called in idtcpconnect, i think i am doing it all wrong, i am not sure how i can have a unique global variable for each context.

Comment: In the connect callback, is AContext actually of type TMyContext? If not, it won't have allocated space for your FPacketBuffer field and this will blow up.

Comment: TMyContext is a class of tidservercontext

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but when MainSckConnect is called has it somehow been intercepted beforehand to allocate a TMyConnect rather than a regular TIdContext. Casting to TMyConnect doesn't magically change the type - it just tells the compiler to assume that it is a TMyConnect instance.

Comment: I have assigned the contextclass property of the server to tmycontext so a new instance of tmycontext is automatically created when a connection comes in.

Comment: Yes, that is a requirement. Now that you fixed that, `TIdTCPServer` already keep track of the clients for you, in its `Contexts` property, so you should not need to keep track of them manually in your `Clients` list as well.

Comment: Rather then using `GetMem()`, I would suggest declaring `FPacketBuffer` as a dynamic `array of Byte` instead of a `Pointer`, and then use `SetLength()` to allocate and deallocate it when needed. If the size never changes, then it would be better to declare `FPacketBuffer` as a static `array[WORD] of Byte` instead and do not dynamically allocate/deallocate it at all, since it will be allocated for you whenever `TMyContext` is instantiated.

Comment: I tried and changed the FPaketbuffer to TIdBytes and instead of GetMem i used SetLength and set its length to 65535 but still no luck. works fine when a client is connecting if there are no connections but when there is already a connection and new client tries to connect the setlength operation give error

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are assigning your class type to the `TIdTCPServer.ContextClass` property before activating the server at runtime, eg:

```
procedure TMainFrm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MainSck.ContextClass := TMyContext;
end;
```

Comment: Yes it has been assigned before activating the server. and i dont know why but the very first client doesnt have issues with connecting, but if there is already a connection and the FPacketbuffer isnt freed then a new connection causes an erorr, doesnt it means that the variable isnot unique to each context? if a client connects and disconnects then there is no issue but if there is already a connection before then error is generated.

Comment: I assure you, every `TIdContext` object is unique, and thus its data members are unique to each connected client. So something else is likely going wrong in code you have not shown yet, and your client code is just a victim of circumstance. For example, if your `Clients` list is not thread-safe and is corrupting memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the class of a [already created] object instance to a different type. The object **is** of the class it was instantiated at creation time.

You can safely cast any object to it's own class or any class it inherits of, because the object IS of that class. In a hard cast (like you're doing), you're telling the compiler you know what you're doing, for example:

```
type
  TMyButton: TButton
  public
    FMyField: array[1..50] of byte;
  end;

var
  Button: TButton;
begin
  //next line is valid, a variable of type TButton can reference any object 
  //inheriting from TButton or a TButton instance directly
  Button := TMyButton.Create(nil);
  //next line contains a valid cast, because Button contains a reference to
  //a instance of TMyButton
  TMyButton(Button).FMyField[10] := 5;
  //valid, a TButton variable referencing a TButton instance
  Button := TButton.Create(nil);
  //next line is invalid and may cause an AV or in the worst case 
  //you may corrupt memory by doing that
  TMyButton(AButton).FMyField[20] := 5; 
end;
```

The fact is, in your OnConnect event, you get an already created instance of TIdContext (or a descendant type).

If you want this object to belong to your class, you have to first ask the server to create objects of that class, via the ContextClass property. You have to do this before the Active property of the server is set to true.

```
procedure TMyForm.Init;
begin
  MyServer.ContextClass := TMyContext;
  MyServer.Active := True;
end;
```

And finally, if you have object references, you have to create the objects on the context constructor, or add a Late create mechanism if you don't want to waste memory and you don't use it too often:

```
TMyContext = class(TIdServerContext)
private
  FQueue: TIdThreadSafeList;
public
  constructor Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TThreadList = nil); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  property Queue: TIdThreadSafeList read FQueue;
end;

constructor TMyContext.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TThreadList = nil);
begin
  inherited;
  FQueue := TIdThreadSafeList.Create(Parameters);
end;

destructor TMyContext.Destroy;
begin
  FQueue.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHEWWWW! i was killing myself about what is wrong, i was thinking that the FPacetBuffer variable isnt unique to each connection but after alot of debugging and commenting out code sections i saw the problem and i was like WHATTT!!!!

In processing a login packet data i declared a PChar variable and copied data using StrLCopy to it and retrieved the size of the data and then assigned a null character myself to it (and that was the problem line).

```
Size := (Packet.BufferSize-SizeOf(TLoginPacket));
GetMem(UserName,Size);
StrLCopy(UserName, PChar(Cardinal(Packet)+SizeOf(TLoginPacket)),Size);
UserName[Size] := #0;  <--- This Line here
```

The size variable was holding real size + 2 in it.

Thanks for all the help guys :)